# Ford Escape Alternator Working Intermittently

Tags: electrical, ford, alternator, escape

On my 2004 Ford Escape V-6, I replaced both the battery and alternator about a year ago. The alternator seems to be working intermittently now, and when it does work it only creates about 12.50 volts. What could cause this?

Comment: Could be a wiring issue or the alternator just crapped out. Take some voltage readings with a multimeter. You want to do battery - to alternator, battery + to alternator and battery - to engine ground. Make sure there isn't excessive voltage drop on any of those readings. Check your fuses. Terminal A on the alternator should have ignition voltage on it.

Comment: Do the @Ben test, or have your alternator tested for free at a car parts store. :)

Comment: Sounds like the alternator is operating in a an alternating manner ;-)